# Not able to delete user from iTunes Connect Users and Roles

Tags: app-store-connect, developer-program

I am trying to delete a user from iTunes Connect users and roles tab. This user was provided a developer role and has not accepted the invitation. The invitation is already expired. When ever I click on Edit and select the user and again click on delete it doesn't seems to do anything and the user remains in the list as it is below is the screen shot for same.

[image: Not Able to delete user]

Comment: Same here, i can't remove an expired invitation or not accepted invitation

Comment: Me too. How annoying.